# How does RNA polymerase achieve higher processivity?

Tags: transcription, dna-replication

DNA polymerase uses a sliding clamp in order to replicate DNA. RNA polymerase does not require one. What allows RNA polymerase to hold on to DNA just like DNA polymerase?

Comment: Hi @notorious. Could you add a citation for this sliding clamp usage? I'm rather intruiged!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The structure in the presence of s (holoenzyme) is on the right; note the open channel for DNA binding. The structure in the absence of s (the core enzyme) is on the left.  Note that the channel is now closed, as if the fingers and thumbs of a hand now closed to make a circle. This striking conformational change that occurs when s dissociates is thought to confer high processivity on the RNA polymerase.

SOURCE: http://biowiki.ucdavis.edu/Genetics/Unit_III%3A_The_Pathway_of_Gene_Expression/10%3A_Transcription%3A_RNA_polymerases

Comment: DNA Polymerase III Holoenzyme has processivity of 500,000 bases. High isn't a number,

Comment: If you have nothing to add to the discussion and if you continue criticizing other people's answers without giving a proper explanation to the question, then you really shouldn't be using StackExchange. Also, you still haven't corrected the error in the question.

Comment: And here is another point that you are missing. RNA polymerase need only associate with the template strand of DNA and transcribe from that, where as DNA polymerization is a far more complex process involving leading and lagging strand synthesis, laying down or RNA primers, producing Okazaki fragments and performing exonuclease error correction with DNA polymerase working with both strands of DNA at the same time.

Comment: Perhaps you can add some details on processivities of DNA and RNA polymerases. This will clarify the point. Also cite references for those. [BioNumbers](http://bionumbers.hms.harvard.edu/search.aspx?log=y&task=searchbytrmorg&trm=processivity&org=) is a good place to look for figures such as these.

Comment: @AMR DNA-polymerase, unaided by sliding clamp has a low processivity. Highest seems that of viral polymerases ([7200 for EBV](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1662485)).

Comment: @AMR I remember being scorned for almost exactly the same thing in a college (UK) biology class. I said there was a "high amount" of something I can no longer recall. I now fear the words "high" and "amount". Specificity is key for, if nothing else, not angering teachers and biologists.